# How to get real-time contours from canny detected edges C# forms?

Tags: c#, image-processing, contour, emgucv, canny-operator

I want to find contours from canny detected edges. To do that: I have applied canny filter to real time monitoring from webcam. It works fine and finding the edges as i desired in real-time.
But i have problem to find contours. When i click button which i placed to find contours. I find contours but only for the clicked time frame.
I want to find contours in real-time. I saw some tutorials but i could not figure out them to be new C# and image processing.
I am not sure how to go on. I think i have problem about conversion of real time video to image or something like that.
Please tell me what is wrong in my code. By the way i checked Query Frame, but i think it is not the solution.

First i am adding how i applied canny.
After that, i am trying to find contours with button. For that i am using the code:

```
private void btnDetect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        device = new VideoCaptureDevice(filter[cboDevice.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        device.NewFrame += Device_NewFrame;
        device.Start();
    }

    static readonly CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new 
    CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");

    public void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        Bitmap video2 = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        if (mode == 1)
        {
            Grayscale gray = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
            Bitmap video3 = gray.Apply(video2);
            CannyEdgeDetector canny = new CannyEdgeDetector(0, 20);
            canny.ApplyInPlace(video3);
            pic.Image = video3;

        }
        else
            pic.Image = video;
    } 


    private void btnKontur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    //Image<Bgr, byte> ImgInput;
    var ImgInput = new Bitmap(pic.Image).ToImage<Bgr, byte>();

    //imgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(pic2.Image);
    //ImgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(pic2.Image);
    pic.Image = ImgInput.ToBitmap();
    Image<Gray, byte> ImgOutput = ImgInput.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new 
    Gray(100), new Gray(150)); //Binarization
    Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
    Mat hier = new Mat();

    CvInvoke.FindContours(ImgOutput, contours, hier, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, 
    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
    CvInvoke.DrawContours(ImgInput, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));

    pic2.Image = ImgInput.ToBitmap();

    }
```

Comment: Class objects are passed by REF (not value).  It looks like you code is sometimes using the events and other times using "pic".  You should use the object passed in the parameter list.  Make sure you are using the correct object when processing.  Draw a block diagram and make sure each stage is getting correct inputs and outputs.

Comment: @jdweng Can you suggest me any reference document which i can follow?